# execute function not more than one time

Tags: jquery

I wrote the code shown below to call lightbox show and callback some function, for example function_a, but it will fire 16 times.

How can I make it fire only once?

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $('.a, .b, .c, .d').fadeOut(600,function(){
        $('.e, .f, .g, .h').fadeIn(400,function(){
            function_a();
        });
    });
});

function_a(){
    console.log('fire')
};
```

Comment: when do you want it fired? When the last fadeOut completes? When the first one does?

Comment: Why is it firing 16 times? Are you using the #open several times?

Comment: Well the best way would be bug-fix to stop it firing 16 times, but you could also just add a count variable and check it is 0 before firing

Comment: I know if I put in $('.a, .b, .c, .d').fadeOut() callback  will fire 4 times,  I guess maybe because it select 4 item fadeout than call fire 4 times.

Comment: @James how to add count variable to check, can you show me some code for example? Thanks

Comment: The solution posted by asifsid88 is what I was describing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`$.fn.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), f.ex:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $('.a, .b, .c, .d').fadeOut(600).promise().done(function(){
        $('.e, .f, .g, .h').fadeIn(400).promise().done(function(){
            function_a();
        });
    });
});
```

From the docs:

> The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is
>   resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection,
>   queued or not, have ended.

Also note that [classNames must be at least 2 characters long](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner).

Comment: (+1) adding knowledge. Awesome... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you may have 16 elements which class having those specified
Have a variable to keep the track of it

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    var iCount=0;
    $('.a, .b, .c, .d').fadeOut(600,function(){
        $('.e, .f, .g, .h').fadeIn(400,function(){
            if(iCount==0)
               function_a();
            iCount++;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var fired = 0; 
$("#open").click(function(){
    $('.a, .b, .c, .d').fadeOut(600,function(){
        $('.e, .f, .g, .h').fadeIn(400,function(){
            if (fired < 1) function_a();
            fired ++;
        });
    });
});

function_a(){
    console.log('fire')
};
```

Comment: please note this [has already been suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1311994/asifsid88)

Comment: i can see, it wasn't when i was posting, sorry @JanDvorak